# Scrapy NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm completely new to Python and I'm doing summer independent practical project about web scraping where I'm trying to use Scrapy. So far I've used http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html to begin, but due to tutorial spider not working as intended I've had to improvise. OS is win7

I tried to copy the tutorial code and improvise on it resulting in this error:

> ```
> File ..\spiders\dmoz_spider.py", line 16 in DmozSpider with open(filename, 
> 'wb') as f:
> NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
> ```

The code is:

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "turo"
    allowed_domains = ["turotarjoo.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://turotarjoo.com/siipiravintola/",
        "http://turotarjoo.com/info/"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    filename = None
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Thank you for your help and sorry if my first question is hard to read. If you have any tips for starting python programmer or web scraping please do tell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error is not coming from this code.

Comment: Is your indentation correct/consistent with your actual code?  It looks like `parse` was meant to be a method on `DmozSpider` (due to the use of `self`), but as it's written, you have a module-level function instead.  Also, you should check that you aren't mixing spaces and tabs (`python -tt script.py`)

Comment: If was module-level, it would complain about `self`.

Comment: I don' think this is the best tutorial for someone who is "completely new to Python". Maybe look at a basic python tutorial first.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 -- Right, but there's something definitely fishy here as I can't see any reason why you'd get a `NameError` there when `filename` obviously _looks_ like it's been defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scrapy
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "turo"
    allowed_domains = ["turotarjoo.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://turotarjoo.com/siipiravintola/",
        "http://turotarjoo.com/info/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

I only fixed the indentation and it seems to be working fine. Can you try this code?

Comment: Thank you, I got it working by checking the indentation and I had spaces and tabs mixed (which I didn't know about but my friend helped me).